# How do you store an array of strings in C and print it back?

Tags: c, arrays, visual-c++

I am studying 'The C Programming Language' by Brian Kerningham & Dennis Ritchie.

I'm stuck on 1.9 Character Arrays.

I'm trying to allow the user to input multiple lines of text into the CMD that will then be stored in an array of strings parameter for use by another program. Each new line should be stored as a new object in the array. For now all I want to do is print the Array back to the CMD so I can see its working correctly, any ideas what i am doing wrong?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
 int main(char string[])
 {
    int c, i;
    char * strs[i];
      for (i=0; i<5 && (c!=EOF()) && c!='\n'; i++){
         strs[i] = c;
      }
      for(i=0; i<5; ++i)
         puts(strs[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has quite a number of mistakes in it.

1. Your `main()` prototype is wrong, it should be `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);` or something equivalent. Dropping the initial `int` argument is not OK.
2. You're declaring `strs` as an array of character pointers (without a valid size!), you probably want a full 2D array of chars, like `char strs[100][32];`. Limited, but simpler to manage.
3. You're storing characters, so you need to keep track of which character index is the current one in the current string. `strs[i] = c;` should be something like `strs[i][j++] = c;`. Of course you must also respect the maximum length for each string, and terminate the string properly.
4. You need to step to the next string (increment `i`) on newline.

Comment: Isn't another mistake is uninitialized value of variable c(or probably garbage value of c)?

Comment: Basically I doubt if there is anything right in this program.